Arrayformula not populating correctly
I have two columns with text in the first column (D) and a number in the second (E).  In the third column (F) I put the following:
=IF(OR(E1=2,E1=3),"TRUE","NOT2OR3")
This works fine. If I copy this cell down the column, everything works fine. Column E is 0 in the first row so it shows NOT2OR3, and when it gets to a row with a 2 or 3 in Column E it shows TRUE.
BUT, if I change this to:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(OR(E1:E=2,E1:E=3),"TRUE","NOT2OR3"))
It only shows the first row, and it say TRUE (when it should be NOT2OR3)
What am I doing wrong that it does not populate the whole column?
Thanks,
Doc
